# How does the Feedback Loop card work in Gloomhaven?

Tags: gloomhaven

I've seen a lot of FAQ's about the Feedback Loop Card in Gloomhaven, but they always refer to the augment portion which seems straight forward to me. However I am a little confused about the bottom portion of the card:

[image: Feedback loop]

Is this like saying "all the enemies I moved through I now target with muddle"?

Or is it like saying "the enemies I moved through are muddled and I now target them with this attack"?

Or another way to phrase it. Do I get to attack my freshly muddled targets? Or do I get to muddle my freshly moved through targets

This would help my upcoming scenario any help greatly appreciated.

**Edit:** Can I use the bottom half of this card to target and the top half of another card to attack those targets

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You get to muddle the targets you moved through. In gloomhaven, the top and bottom halves of the card are separate, once you have chosen to use the bottom half of this card, you ignore the top half completely, this means you:

> Perform muddle, targeting all enemies you moved through.

With no other enhancements that would mean you have moved through up to two enemy occupied hexes, and back to your starting position in a triangle shaped movement.

This also does not change the targets of the card you chose to play the top half of. You can attack your freshly muddled targets by using this move, then another attack, but it will target as normal.

Comment: Right I understand that, but if I've used the bottom half of Feedback loop can i use the top half of a card to attack my targeted enemies? or am i only targeting them with muddle

Comment: @TylerGriffith Only muddle, the top half of the card is not part of the bottom half ability in any card in gloomhaven.

Comment: Thanks @Andrew i know that the halves are separate. my question is that the wording is unclear as to whether i can perform an attack action with a separate cards top half with the targets I've created using the bottom half of feedback loop

Comment: @TylerGriffith I realized that and edited to answer that part.

Comment: @TylerGriffith On your turn you get two actions. One is the top of one of your cards and the other is the bottom of the other. They are independent of each other, you resolve one completely then resolve the other. Doing the bottom on this one *may* enhance your second card in that some of the attacks do extra damage for every status effect on an enemy (and Muddle is a status effect), but doing the bottom half doesn't directly affect what you can do with your other card's top half.